# How to synthesize speech to an audio file in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In Android, the TTS api can synthesize text into an audio file - [synthesizeToFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#synthesizeToFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.HashMap%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%3E,%20java.lang.String%29). Can the same thing be done using Windows Phone?

Comment: In windows 8 this can be done , Pls check http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Speech-synthesis-sample-6e07b218/sourcecode?fileId=86737&pathId=1758936919, For windows phone I dnt find any methods like SynthesizeSsmlToStreamAsync to write the stream to .wav file..

Comment: That's sad. I can only say that whoever is designing this api is quite stupid. How can he/she not anticipate this usage? And android had this api long ago. On the other hand, can I record or capture the audio output of the phone?

Comment: This is as per my understanding..but there should be some way to do this.. cos this is pretty basic..

Comment: For audio recording pls refer http://independentinnovation.net/blogs/independentinnovation/archive/2012/12/11/Windows-Phone-8-Audio-Recording-using-Windows.Phone.Media.Capture.aspx

Comment: I don't think that could be done, imgen . But you can use an online service to get it or use a tts library, maybe? @PrasannaAarthi , Also, you can get real world sounds too!